# How do i create a new row in a database table in django with a submit button and innerHTML names as the data fields?

Tags: django

I would like to create a new row in my Logofsupport datatable based on the users checked inputs maybe i am going about this the wrong wat, but i would like to grab some innerHTML and insert it in for the servername and rootname then pull out the date which should be easy and based on a drop down menu pick an action that will be appended to the action field then submit the data which will basically be the save function i believe in django.

```
 def log(request):
     cust = Logofsupport.objects.create(servername= "innerHTML FIELD",rootname="innerHTML
                 FIELD", requesteddate="innerHTML FIELD", action="Submit Form FIELD")

    return render_to_response('status/log.html', {'add':cust},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my HTML i would like to check the row and based on check being true grab the rootname, requestdate, and the action based on the value of the drop down box then create a new row to add to my sql table after the submit button has been clicked. I am more interested in how to create the form code.

---

```
  <body>
<div id="container">
    <div id = "left" >
        {%for status in root|slice:":1" %}
    <h1><center>Root List by {{status.rootgroup}} Rootgroup<center></h1>
    {% endfor %}
        <h3 id="time">current:  </h3>
        <table border = "2">

            <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>   Check All</th>
                <th>Rootname </th>
                <td>Urls</td>
                <th> custs </th>
                <th> jvmms </th>
                <th> x64 </th>
                <th> currentplatform </th>
                <th> currentjdk </th>
                <th> currenttomcat </th>
                <td><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="10" /></p></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="12:00" size="5" /><td>
            <select name="ampm">
                <option value="am">AM</option>
                <option value="pm">PM</option>
            </select>
            </tr>
                {% for status in root %}
            <tr id="l{{forloop.counter}}">
            <form name= "info" action="">
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" onclick="resetSelectedAll(this);" id="row{{ forloop.counter }}" ></td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}rootname">{{ status.rootname }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}urls">{{ status.urls }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}custs">{{ status.custs }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}jvmms"> {{ status.jvmms }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}x64">{{ status.x64 }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currentplatform"> {{ status.currentplatform }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currentjdk"> {{ status.currentjdk }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currenttomcat">{{ status.currenttomcat }}</td>
            </tr>

                {% endfor %}

        </table>
        <select name="buttons">
            <option value="Restart">Restart</option>
            <option value="Full_Dump">Full_Dump</option>
            <option value="Redeploy">Redeploy</option>
            <option value="Thread">Thread</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" onclick="check()" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    </div>
```

This was my attempt in creating a form that would use a checkbox, with the hopes it would make it easier to create a new row I am a little lose.

---

```
class LogofsupportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myboolean = forms.BooleanField()
    servername = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    rootname = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    requesteddate = forms.DateTimeField() # Field name made lowercase.
    action = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    loginname = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    result = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        model= Logofsupport
        fields = ['servername', 'rootname', 'requesteddate', 'action','loginname',
                  'result']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right:
If you want to use django.forms to validate your posted data, you need to give the HTML form input fields unique names. Since the data you want to post are not in HTML input fields, I suggest you use javascript to extract the values and post via AJAX, like jQuery.post().

Comment: I would prefer not using ajax however one of the bigger issues i am having is inserting the data back into the database. I will test out your theory however.